# Color Box In Legend Contains Alphabets In R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `ggplot2` to code a donut chart using code from R-graph-gallery. The code is as below.

```
ggplot(AcademicCount, aes (ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, xmax = 4, xmin = 3, fill =`Academic Qualifications`)) +
  geom_rect() +
  geom_label_repel(x = 3.5, y = AcademicCount$labelPosition, label = AcademicCount$label, size = 3) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  xlim(c(1,4)) +
  theme_void()
```

However, the color box in the legends contain the alphabet 'a' even though the site provided output does not. I have tried copying and running the site's code and no 'a' was seen in the legend color boxes.

[image]

Is there any problem with my code, or am I just missing something?

(edit) This is the `dput` output of my data frame:

```
structure(list(`Academic Qualifications` = c("Certificate", "Degree", 
"Diploma", "Master's", "Not Stated", "Primary", "SPM", "STPM"
), Count = c(46, 450, 487, 2, 113, 4, 119, 9), fraction = c(0.0373983739837398, 
0.365853658536585, 0.395934959349593, 0.0016260162601626, 0.091869918699187, 
0.0032520325203252, 0.0967479674796748, 0.00731707317073171), 
    ymax = c(0.0373983739837398, 0.403252032520325, 0.799186991869919, 
    0.800813008130081, 0.892682926829268, 0.895934959349593, 
    0.992682926829268, 1), ymin = c(0, 0.0373983739837398, 0.403252032520325, 
    0.799186991869919, 0.800813008130081, 0.892682926829268, 
    0.895934959349593, 0.992682926829268), percentage = c(3.73983739837398, 
    36.5853658536585, 39.5934959349593, 0.16260162601626, 9.1869918699187, 
    0.32520325203252, 9.67479674796748, 0.731707317073171), labelPosition = c(0.0186991869918699, 
    0.220325203252033, 0.601219512195122, 0.8, 0.846747967479675, 
    0.894308943089431, 0.944308943089431, 0.996341463414634), 
    label = c("46\n (3.74%)", "450\n (36.59%)", "487\n (39.59%)", 
    "2\n (0.16%)", "113\n (9.19%)", "4\n (0.33%)", "119\n (9.67%)", 
    "9\n (0.73%)")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hi Ryan! Thanks for providing your code - the first 7 lines are not helpful - instead, could you edit your question to include the output of `dput(AcademicCount)` (it starts with "structure(...)"). This will help make the question reproducible and get you better, faster help. Thanks and good luck!

Comment: Add `geom_label_repel(... show.legend = FALSE)`

Comment: Many thanks to @s_baldur 's comment - after adding it, the problem is solved. Also thanks for the help on my question, I'll edit it accordingly and I hope it will be alright for the community.